# Can we deduce the $|\Psi_z\rangle$ from knowledge about $|\Psi_x\rangle$ and $|\Psi_y\rangle$ without measuring?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-measurements

If a spin in z direction is measure as $|u\rangle$ that is $|\Psi_z\rangle=|u\rangle$ then $|\Psi_x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|d\rangle$ and $|\Psi_y\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|d\rangle$.

Is the opposite of this correct as well, meaning that if we are told that for a particle $|\Psi_x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|d\rangle$ and $|\Psi_y\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|d\rangle$, can we conclude that for sure $|\Psi_z\rangle=|u\rangle$?

Comment: why can’t it be $\vert d\rangle$?

Comment: I thought if it is going to be $|d\rangle$ then it has to be that $|\Psi_x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|d\rangle$ and $|\Psi_y\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|u\rangle - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|d\rangle$, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once you choose a base, the state is always perfectly defined.
You don't even need to know both the expressions of $|\Psi_x>$ and $|\Psi_y>$, you just need one.
For example, since

$|u_x> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_z> + |d_z>)$

$|d_x> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_z> - |d_z>)$

You can pass from base $x$ to base $z$:

$|\Psi> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_x> + |d_x>) = \frac{1}{2}(|u_z> + |d_z> + |u_z> - |d_z>) = |u_z>$

Comment: But then how are we supposed to get from $|u_x\rangle$ and $|d_x\rangle$ to $|d_z\rangle$?

Comment: @alpal To get from $|u_x⟩$ and $|d_x⟩$ to $|d_z⟩$, you can just write $|d_z⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_x⟩-|d_x⟩)$. It is just a change of basis. Given your comment, I feel like I am missing the point of the question, could you please clarify?

Comment: In fact you gave me the answer I was looking for, thanks. But one question: How would we get from $|u_y\rangle$ and $|d_y\rangle$ to $|d_z\rangle$? Wouldn't it result in $i|d_z\rangle$? Or $i|d_z\rangle$ is in fact the same state as $|d_z\rangle$?

Comment: $|d_z⟩=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_y⟩−i|d_y⟩)$
Check out the [pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), they may help you with this kind of calculation

Comment: Isn't there any mistake in the $|d_z\rangle$ you provided? Because I don't get the correct answer when I calculate it: $|d_z\rangle=\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_y\rangle-i|d_y\rangle)=
\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{|u_z\rangle+i|d_z\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}-i\frac{|u_z\rangle-i|d_z\rangle}{\sqrt{2}})=
\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{|u_z\rangle+i|d_z\rangle-i|u_z\rangle-|d_z\rangle}{\sqrt {2}})=
\frac{-i|u_z\rangle+|d_z\rangle-|u_z\rangle+i|d_z\rangle}{2}
$, or maybe I am making a mistake somewhere!

Comment: Also would you please tell me how we can get from Pauli matrices to lets say $|d_z\rangle=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_y\rangle - i|d_y\rangle)$?

Comment: you are right, it should be $|d_z⟩=−\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_y⟩−|d_y⟩)$.
The pauli matrices are the spin 1/2 operators written in base z. Therefore, if you calculate their eigenvectors, you have everything written in terms of $|u_z⟩$ and $|d_z⟩$. Such eigenvectors are already handily calculated in the Wikipedia page I linked. To express the state in terms of (say) $|u_y⟩$ and $|d_y⟩$, you just have to invert the linear system of equations